# I lost my uncommited changes after I made a merge

Tags: git, github, merge, github-for-mac

I am new in git and I got all my changes lost.

I made a branch for my changes, and then I wanted to make a merge.

So i switched to master and merge my branch with master, but I forgot to make a commit. So now my branch looks like the same as master.

Made the merge with [GitHub client for Mac](http://mac.github.com/), it didn't throw any errors...

How can I restore my uncommitted changes?

**Here's the history of my terminal. But all these were typed after I've found out that my changes were lost and tried to google the answer.**

> 506  git checkout master
>
> 507  git merge storyboard_branch
>
> 508  git reflog
>
> 509  git reset --hard HEAD~1
>
> 510  git reset --hard HEAD~0
>
> 511  git reflog
>
> 512  git reset --hard HEAD~1
>
> 513  git reset --hard HEAD@1
>
> 514  git reset --hard HEAD^@1
>
> 515  git reset --hard ^HEAD@1
>
> 516  git reset --merge HEAD~1
>
> 517  git reflog
>
> 518  git reset --merge HEAD~5
>
> 519  git reset --merge HEAD~7
>
> 520  git reset --merge HEAD~7
>
> 521  git reflog
>
> 522  git reset --merge HEAD~14
>
> 523  git reset --merge HEAD~14
>
> 524  git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
>
> 525  ды
>
> 526  ls
>
> 527  cd .git
>
> 528  ls
>
> 529  grep -ri stroyboard_branch
>
> 530  cd ..
>
> 531  git checkout
>
> 532  git checkout storyboard_branch
>
> 533  git pull origin
>
> 534  git checkout storyboard_branch
>
> 535  git reflog
>
> 536  git reset --merge HEAD~22
>
> 537  git checkout
>
> 538  git commit -c HEAD~16
>
> 539  git reset --merge
>
> 540  git reset --merge
>
> 541  git reflog

Comment: do you mean you forgot to commit before switching to `master`, or before making the merge?

Comment: both, I forgot to make a commit and switched to master and then make the merge

Comment: then the merge shouldnt do nothing.. your changes should be still on the master branch

Comment: my changes were on other branch, which I wanted to merge with master

Comment: the command git merge dont remove un commit changes.
so they should not been deleted. did you execute any more commands?

Comment: I updated the question, added the history of command from terminal

Comment: yep.. after the reset --hard all is doom.. sorry!

Comment: Please denote, which data you have lost, already commited inside a deep of git repo, or uncommitted? If second, please show us `git stash show` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't committed the changes and you checked out another branch git will not store the files it will overwrite them with the branch you specified.

This being said there is **NO** way to recover the lost data, except if you used git stash beforehand.

**Commit Early, Commit Often**

Comment: if you make changes in a branch. dont commit them and move to another branch. one of those can happen:
  1. move to the branch and the changes will move with you
  2. git wont let you move to the branch since their are conflicts in the chages.

Comment: sad but true :/

Answer (score 0):

You can recover the lost uncommitted changes if there is a track of your local history option in IDE

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).